# Strange error from Apache JackRabbit

Tags: java, apache, jcr, jackrabbit

Anyone ever get this exception from Apache JackRabbit?
This exception occurs on RHEL 6 Linux.

```
ERROR RepositoryImpl:393 - In addition to startup fail, another unexpected problem occurred while shutting down the repository again.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.doShutdown(RepositoryImpl.java:1141)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.shutdown(RepositoryImpl.java:1065)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:389)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:605)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository$1.getRepository(TransientRepository.java:180)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.startRepository(TransientRepository.java:280)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.login(TransientRepository.java:376)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractRepository.login(AbstractRepository.java:123)
Exception in thread java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getDriverDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:312)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.createDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem.getDataSource(DbFileSystem.java:226)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem.init(DatabaseFileSystem.java:190)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$6.getFileSystem(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:1057)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig.getFileSystem(RepositoryConfig.java:911)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:605)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository$1.getRepository(TransientRepository.java:180)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.startRepository(TransientRepository.java:280)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.login(TransientRepository.java:376)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractRepository.login(AbstractRepository.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: If you need to know why it is not starting up you need to look at the first error, not the last. Once the repo does not start properly all kinds of errors are expected at the shutdown phase.

Comment: Thanks, eckes...any idea how to enable logging for JackRabbit?  Maybe that'll help me track down the issue.

Comment: If you embed it you need to set up the logger infrastucture. Jackrabbit uses as far as I remeber log4j, so load it and configure it to log. The standalone server does write a logfile on its own in repository/log. BTW: there is a "class not found" in your output, did you provide all needed dependencies? (*Commons Pool* in this case)

Comment: Yes...all the dependencies are there...I'm using the same distribution package and configuration on a Windows box and in a different flavor of Linux -- only the RHEL system has this issue.   Thanks for the tip, I'll try to get the log4j working...

Comment: Did you find a solution ?